# Google AdWords click conversion is "unverified"

Tags: asp.net, google-ads-api

I've got an online store build on ASP.NET web forms. When a customer goes to the checkout page, there is a form, where they have to provide their details, like postage address etc. After they filled the form in they have to click "Pay now" button to be prompted to go to Paypal checkout page.

I need to track those clicks for the Google AdWords conversion statistics.

The usual code for tracking clicks would look like:

```
// some data
goog_report_conversion = function(url) {
goog_snippet_vars();
window.google_conversion_format = "3";
var opt = new Object();
opt.onload_callback = function() {
if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
  window.location = url;
}
```

But because of the way the website was implemented, the destination link is being generated dynamically, so I couldn't pass it as as argument for "goog_report_conversion".

So I've slightly changed the conversion function to this:

```
// some data
goog_report_conversion = function(id) {
goog_snippet_vars();
window.google_conversion_format = "3";
var opt = new Object();
opt.onload_callback = function() {
  if (typeof(id) != 'undefined') {
    // I use custom function to trigger click on the actual button
    event_fire(document.getElementById(id), 'click');
  }
}
```

And I have this HTML structure:

```
<span class="GeneralFormButton" onClick="goog_report_conversion('submit_all')">Pay Now</span>
<input type="button" name="submit_all" value="Pay Now" onclick="this.disabled=true; this.value='Plase wait';__doPostBack('submit_all','')" id="submit_all" style="display: none;" />
```

Where `<span>` is being used to trigger the conversion function and then to emulate "click" on the actual submit button.

It works well and the customer is redirected to Paypal. However, the conversion isn't tracked and in Google AdWords account my "Pay with Paypal" option is marked as "Unverified" (It's been going for a way longer than 24 hors)

I tested what data is sent to google on submit:

```
https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/*correct conversion id*/?random=1459744659796
&cv=8
&fst=1459744659796
&num=1
&fmt=3
&label=*correct conversion label*
&guid=ON
&u_h=800
&u_w=1280
&u_ah=777
&u_aw=1280
&u_cd=24
&u_his=11
&u_tz=570
&u_java=false
&u_nplug=5
&u_nmime=7
&frm=0
&url=http%3A//www.website.com/store_checkout2.aspx%3Fpay_service%3DPayPal%26promo_code%3D%26voucher%3D
&ref=http%3A//www.website.com/store_checkout2.aspx%3Fpay_service%3DPayPal%26promo_code%3D%26voucher%3D
&tiba=Contact%20and%20Delivery%20Address
&async=1
```

The conversion id and label are correct, the rest of the data seems to be okay too, but the conversion is still not tracked. I just can't figure out why.

Where did I go wrong and what do you think needs to be changed?

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: Hello Vlad V, first of all I wouldn't trigger the conversion in that action because people can go to Paypal and go to another site or return to yours without buying, so, why don't you implement the usual code in you "thank you page"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the form was never completed and sent before, therefore Google couldn't verify the code. While I was testing for response data I sent the form and the code got verified.